# Is there a way to trigger a state change on Next.js frontend when a POST request hits Next.js backend?

Tags: next.js, backend, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS SNS to send a POST request to an HTTP/S endpoint, in this case it's an exposed endpoint on our next.js app.

On incoming requests, the backend should trigger a snackbar notification to popup on the frontend temporarily.

What is the proper way to implement this? Should I be using websockets instead? If so, would I be using the next.js backend as a websocket client, and SNS would sent POST requests hich will be passed through the websockets?

Comment: Websockets are probably the way to go for the type of two-way-communication you are describing. There are dozens of tutorials available on the web centered around this topic. But [here](https://www.bugpilot.io/guides/en/implementing-websocket-communication-in-next-js-d5cf) is one to get you started.